# Shorter way of displaying ActiveRecord object in view than using "attributes" array

Tags: yii, yii2

My `Model` returns this to my `Controller`:

```
namespace app\models;

use yii\data\ActiveDataProvider;
use \yii\db\ActiveRecord;

class Questions extends ActiveRecord{

    public static function getQuestionById($id){
        return Questions::find()->select('title, is_textarea')->where(['id'=>$id])->one();
    }

    public static function model($className=__CLASS__)
    {
        return parent::instance();
    }
}
```

In the `Controller`, it's sent to the `View`:

```
return $this->render('question', ['question' => Question::getQuestionById($id)]);
```

Then in my `View`, I must display the question like such:

```
<?= $question['attributes']['title'] ?>
```

Isn't there a way to display in a more human-friendly way, for example:

```
<?= $question->title ?>
```

I tried it and it's throwing a "Trying to get property of non-object" exception. I thought that was the way to go in Yii, just like Django, CodeIgniter, etc but I can't find an example in the documentation how to display model data in views

Comment: Did you tried change `['questions' => question]` -> `['question' => $question]`?

Comment: Sorry, typo in the question, will fix right now :)

Comment: You need to share more code (controller and model). `$question->title` should work perfectly fine, you probably break something by your own modifications.

Comment: of course, the shorter version should work (if you do everything correctly). But as long as you `["attributes"]` version is working, the shorter one Will work.

Comment: Yeah, I don't get why attributes is working but not the opposite.. @rob006 I added more code

Comment: @NaturalBornCamper Do you overwritten some magic methods or `find()` method in `Question` model?

Comment: Just checked to make sure and the previous dev only implemented tableName, rules, relations, search. and a static method "model" that returns parent::instance(), should I add the latter in the code so you can see?

Answer (score 0):

While sending to the view you are assigning `['questions'=>$question]` so using

```
$questions->title
```

should work

Answer (score 0):

I think you should clarify which are the steps you need to achieve what you want:

1. **Pass the data to your view.** In your case, you want to pass a model of *Questions*. You don't need to pass data from the model to the controller. Actually, the data you need *is the model itself*.

So you can simply do this inside your controller's action:

```
public function actionTest($id)
{
    $question = Questions::findOne(['id' => $id]);
    return $this->render('test', [
        'question' => $question,
    ]);
}
```

2. **Display the data.** Now in your view file you simply access to the model fields that you need:

   `<?= $question->title ?>`

Comment: I tried your solution and using only "findOne(['id' => $id])" in case my "select" was messing things up, but the same is happening. Not sure if I got a wrong namespace or something, I really don't get it

Comment: It's quite strange indeed. I would do a var_dump() of `Question::getQuestionById($id)` and see if it returns an object or just an array. It seems like it's returning an array.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid "Trying to get property of non-object" exception you should check that $question exists

**Controller**

```
public function actionTest($id)
{
    $question = Question::getQuestionById($id);
    if (empty($question)) {
        throw new \yii\web\NotFoundHttpException('Question not found');
    }
    return $this->render('test', [
        'question' => $question,
    ]);
}
```

**View**

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\web\View;
use app\models\Question;

/**
 * @var $this View
 * @var $question Question
 */
?>
<div>
    <h1><?= Html::encode($question->title) ?></h1>
    <p>
        <?= Html::encode($question->is_textarea) ?>
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks friend, that is useful input. $question does exist anyways and I can access its properties via $question['attributes']['title']. Just can't using the short way

Comment: Could you show Question::model() method please?Try to comment Question::model() and check output